# Eclipse and Proxy Auto-Config

Tags: eclipse, networking, proxy, pac

How do you setup Eclipse to work with an auto-configured proxy *with username/password*? Even if I try to get the correct proxy address from the script manually, I can't get Eclipse to recognize the credentials.

I've tried

- setting the Proxy setting to NATIVE within Eclipse -> doesn't ask for credentials, fails
- setting the Proxy setting to MANUAL, setting the (probably) correct proxy ip for the https setting and passing username/password -> fails, doesn't have the credentials on next launch
- putting -Dhttp.proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyUser and proxyPassword into the *eclipse.ini* file -> fails and the Properties - Network settings tab keeps showing the previous settings

Unfortunately, we have a rather restrictive network policy.